# Could not load file or assembly System.Runtime - The assembly reference did not match the assembly definition found

Tags: c#, .net, iis, dependencies, .net-assembly

I am not able to run the website in VS2022 and through IIS.

When i checked the event viewer then i found this error which is related to system.runtime dll.

*Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040).*

After further investigation using Fusion i managed to get to the bottom of this issue. Here is the error i see in the fusion log file.

[image]

Just wondering how to get this resolved. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Likely that you are still using `packages.config` to acquire NuGet dependencies, and then such issues are not surprises. Package references should remedy them, but only partially supported in ASP.NET projects, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files#project-type-support Hint: upgrade to ASP.NET Core as soon as you can.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get the assembly System.Runtime version 6.0.0.0 but it looks like you have the version 4.2.1.0 in your assembly referencing, probably referenced in the file `packages.config` or `app.config` or `web.config`.

Or try to use Nuget Packages to update this dependency.